How to Bevel Edges created by Mesh Boolean node (in Geometry Nodes)?
I have been searching for an answer but none of the solutions I've found are not working for me.  I know the answers here and here (which incidentally is my own similar question) are close, but I'm still stuck.
(Note that when I add a "Realize Instances" node after the Instance on Points node, and then attempt to use the Bevel Modifier, Blender crashes, so I'm hoping that there is another solution.)
Basically I have the following node setup and I want to bevel the edges created by the Mesh Boolean modifier:




Please share your file on blendexchange.com rather than an external site where it won't be permanently available to future users who may be researching the same question.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

@JohnEason done ;)

Thanks. Maybe someone here who knows more than me about geometry nodes will be able to help. Incidentally Blender doesn't crash here if I add a Realize Instances node at the end of your node group but the displayed result disappears.

@JohnEason actually, I missed a key aspect of when Blender crashes- it happens when I attempt to use a Bevel Modifier on the object after the Realize Instances node is added.  I will update the post accordingly.

Your problem is not with the Bevel modifier, but with the Power node in the "MODIFY BASE CURVE" frame. It is returning NaN (Not a Number) for Index equal 0 because of the negative sign of the Exponent (meaning a division by 0). You can track this by plugging a Viewer node to the Instance on Points node. You will see the scale is "nan" for the first instance (of index 0). As a first step, just unplug the Scale socket, and it should work (at least it is for me using Blender 3.6.12).

@StefLAncien that is very interesting, I did not realize that was happening.  The problem is that I need my Scale node setup to create the effect I'm after.  Is there a way around this?

You can add $10^{-6}$ to the Index before the Powernode to get rid of the NaN. Nevertheless, with such an expression, the Scale will be "close" to infinity. What seems weird for me... What kind of evolution law are you trying to achieve for this scaling factor ?

@StefLAncien thank you for sticking with me. I'm just trying to create a measured "step" effect where each layer is spaced equidistant from the next, but scaled linearly.  In other words, as the layers go down they get smaller, but linearly like stairs. And I want control over the size of the "stairs".  Does that make sense?  For me the Power node was the way to achieve this but I'm not married to it.

Then I suggest to add 1 to the Index before the Power math node. So Scale will be 1 for the first layer (of Index 0), then it will decrease as the Index increases (0.993 for Index 1, 0.989 for Index 2, ...).

@StefLAncien this was exactly the answer I needed, thank you!  I can't believe it was that simple ;)  If you'd like to make this an answer the bounty is yours.

(Using Blender 3.6.12)
Analysis

This picture shows that, with the original GeometryNodes graph, the Scale of the first instance (with Index 0) is "nan" (see the first line, last column, of the Spreadsheet Editor). This means that the Power math node of frame "MODIFY BASE CURVE" is returning a "Not a Number" value. The reason is that $a^b$ is computed as $\exp{(b \ln{(a)})}$ and $ln{(0)}$ is undefined. Consequently, not only the first layer is not displayed, but this "nan" value is most probably confusing the Bevel modifier.
Correction

The simplest correction is to shift by 1 the Index, so the Scale of the first layer is 1 instead of "nan". It is to notice that this layer is now displayed.
Results

With a Realize Instances node inserted before the Group Output node, a Bevel modifier added after the corrected GeometryNodes modifier is working as expected.
Resources
Blender file: 

This was the solution, thanks again!
